# jQuery combobox Styling issue

Tags: jquery-ui, combobox

I am rendering a jQuery combobox, but the height of input element does not match the height of toggle button as shown in screen shot below.  This is happening in  both, IE 9 and FireFox 13.
[image]

The style being used for jQuery combobox is as below.

```
<style>
.ui-combobox {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}
.ui-combobox-toggle {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    margin-left: -1px;
    padding: 0;
    /* adjust styles for IE 6/7 */
    *height: 1.7em;
    *top: 0.1em;
}
.ui-combobox-input {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0.3em;
}
          .ui-autocomplete { height: 200px; overflow-y: auto; }
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should update your combo-box widget from the jqueryui [page](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#combobox). and make sure that you use the latest jquery-ui (this issue was fixed recently).

this helped me...

Comment: You mean, this was fixed sometimes within the last few days. I will try the latest version  and see if that fixes it.